# Design pattern for threading audio in a swing app: How to notify midi executor is shutdown to drive a GUI state-change?

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, swingworker, javasound

My application is displaying various GUI state changes, as well as enabling user input based on which Midi files have successfully completed playing.  What's the best way to wait within a `while` loop that is changing GUI state, playing midi on an `ExecutorService`, updating a model and waiting for the midifile to finish playback before reiterating through the while?  Currently, my code is something like the following:

```
public void startTraining() {
    int i = 0;
    while( i != Model.getTestIteration() + 1) {

        //create GUI state changes and schedule on EDT
        myButton.setButtonSelected( true);
        Timer t = new Timer( DELAY_TIME, new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent avt) {
                 myButton.setButtonSelected( false);
                                 }
                });)
        t.setRepeats( false);
        t.start();

        //MidiplaybackController uses ScheduluedExecutorService
        //to start and stop playback with its own ScheduluedFuture<?> for stopping
        //at a fixed interval
        _midiPlaybackController.playQueue( (int)aCue));

        //TODO: pause somehow relative to midiplayback finishing

        Model.updateTestIteration();
        myButton.setSelected( true);
        i++;
    }
}
```

What's the best pattern here.  I want the state changes to be happening on the EDT,  midistuff on its own thread with scheduling, and then waiting on the midi to bring in another series or GUI state changes.  Should I be creating a `SwingWorker` and then running the Midiplayback `ExecutorServices` within the `SwingWorker`? Or, should I create a something like a `CountDownLatch` at the Todo that is waiting for the midi executor to shutdown and `Timer t` to finish?

Side question: is it wonky to set both icon and selected icon, and then just flip between setSelected( boolean b) calls to reflect a button's state?

Comment: It seems that if I insert a "while" loop at the the TODO, looking something like while( !_midiPlaybackController.isMidiPlaybackDone()) and doing nothing until fScheduluer.isShutdown() updates the flag, all sorts of terrible stuff happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you might get along OK with something like this:

```
_midiPlaybackController.playQueue((int)aCue, new MyMidiPlaybackListener());
```

where `MyMidiPlaybackListener` is a class of your own creation that looks something like this

```
public class MyMidiPlaybackListener implements MidiPlaybackListener
{
    public void onPlaybackComplete()
    {
        // Since onPlaybackComplete is likely called by a worker thread
        // And we don't want to update the GUI from a worker thread
        // (because that would violate Swing's threading policy)
        // we update the GUI via a SwingUtilities.invokeLater Runnable
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                myButton.setSelected(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

The class implements the interface `MidiPlaybackListener`, which is also of your own creation:

```
public interface MidiPlaybackListener 
{
    public void onPlaybackComplete();
}
```

Modify the `playQueue` method of `MidiPlaybackController` to support accepting a listener argument (as shown).  `MidiPlaybackController` must also be modified to store the listener and invoke it at the appropriate time (presumably end of playback).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure you really need a while loop in a GUI. Can you set the GUI up to receive messages? For example, when a MIDI file ends, if that is important info, have the Listener on the MIDI file send whatever message is wanted to the GUI panel, maybe along with an update or repaint().

For SourceDataLine playback, there is a LineListener that can be activated on the end of a playback. I'm pretty sure there is something like this for MIDI playback, too.

[Edit: poking around the tutorial, http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/sound/MIDI-seq-adv.html there is a section "Specifying Special Event Listeners" that might be helpful.]

If I did want to pause a thread, my first choice would be Thread.sleep(). One can send an Interrupt to a sleep command if you need to come out of it sooner than the amount you've chosen. The sleep command's accuracy is limited by the system clock interrupt, and on some Microsoft OS's can be off by up to 15msec--that's the only drawback. Setting up a "wakeup call" from a Timer has the same timing accuracy limitation.

If you put in activity to kill time, you are probably consuming cpu cycles needlessly, slowing down the rest of your program potentially.

I can't say I totally understand your setup from my attempt to read your question, and I hope this is at least somewhat helpful!

Comment: Thanks for the pointers.  Unfortunately, the special event listeners correspond to control messages embedded in the midi file itself.  I'm starting and stopping playback before file completion at random locations in the file, so I don't have any control messages to reliably listen for.  The only thing I have is a Schduler.shutdown() when the Midi thread stops playing.  Also, when using Thread.currentThread.sleep() at the //TODO point I hang the whole thing.  I believe it's putting the EDT to sleep.  Don't I want to shy away from Thread.sleep in swing applications for this reason?

Comment: That is part of why you don't want while loops on a GUI thread! Whatever you are using to Start/Stop the MIDI, why not also use that to "update()" the GUI state? Ditch the while loop, use a callable "update()" method instead. GUI controls (buttons, mouseclicks, etc.) are already waiting to act.

Comment: The midi is happening on its own ExecutorService, which, when the API refers to "managing its own tasks" I assume it runs on its own thread.  GUI updates would need to be on the EDT and not run from the Executor thread.  If I put GUI changes along with Scheduler.shutdown() during Midi thread termination, would I need to EventQueue.invokeLater( new SomeRunnableClassWithGUIThingsToDo());

Comment: "Observer" patterns (you want to observe/be notified..) requires a registration step. Maybe include an instance of the GUI (what is it, a JPanel?) on whatever thread that initiates the MIDI stop? Whether you use synchronized or invokeLater on this JPanel (GUI) method: either should work. Also, I still think you need to lose this while loop. Make the inner loop something that is called once and handle the repeated calls one layer out on an as-needed basis. That's my best guess, not understanding more about your program.